# NSDictionary won't fill up

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I have the following piece of code.

```
-(NSDictionary *)getPlayers
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position ==[c] %@", @"Doelman"];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }else

        for (Team *info in fetchedObjects) {

            [_photos setObject:info.image  forKey:@"player_imgUrl"];
            [_photos setObject:info.name forKey:@"player_name"];


        }
    NSLog(@"%@",_photos);
    return _photos;
```

But for some reason or another my NSLog always gives (null) back. But when I do this

```
[_photos setObject:info.image  forKey:@"player_imgUrl"];
            [_photos setObject:info.name forKey:@"player_name"];

            NSLog(@"name: %@",info.name );
            NSLog(@"url: %@",info.image );
```

It gives the right data back.

Can somebody help?

Kind regards.

Comment: You must not be initializing `_photos` correctly. Show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have instantiated your _photos dictionary somewhere with the following line of code:

```
_photos = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Just defining it as an instance variable or a property is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake which may not be directly connected to the issue. In for loop you always reset name and image for the same key. so at the end of the loop your dictionary must have one name and one image, not all the ones from the array. You should change it

UPDATE:probably something like this:

```
int count = fetchedObjects.count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   NSString *image_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player_imgUrl%d",i];
   NSString *name_key =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player_name%d",i];

  [_photos setObject:[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] image]  forKey:image_key];
  [_photos setObject:[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] name] forKey:name_key];
}
```